# Multiple wcf services in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to run multiple WCF services under IIS on the same base URL (so my project has multiple .svc files).  Everything works fine when I have a single service, but the problem comes when I add additional services.  When I try and access any of these additional services the clients seem to think that the contract is the "IMerchantService" contract.  For example if I browse to http://merchants.localtest.me/MerchantProductService.svc?wsdl (the address of the locally hosted service) the service definition returned is that of IMerchantService and not IMerchantProductService.  In addition when I browse to http://merchants.localtest.me/MerchantProductService.svc the title is "MerchantService" and not "MerchantProductService" as I would expect.

My service configuration is as follows:

```
  <services>
  <service name="MyCompany.Services.Merchants.MerchantProductService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Proto.Common.EndpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Common" contract="MyCompany.Api.Merchants.Services.IMerchantProductService"/>
    <endpoint address="mexMerchantProductService"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service name="MyCompany.Services.Merchants.MerchantService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Proto.Common.EndpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Common" contract="MyCompany.Api.Merchants.Services.IMerchantService"/>
    <endpoint address="mexMerchantService"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
  </service>
  <service name="MyCompany.Services.Merchants.Workflows.NewMerchantWorkflow">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Proto.Common.EndpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Common" contract="MyCompany.Api.Merchants.Services.INewMerchantServiceWorkflow"/>
    <endpoint address="mexNewMerchantWorkflow"
  binding="mexHttpBinding"
  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service name="MyCompany.Services.Merchants.MerchantFreightService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Proto.Common.EndpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Common" contract="MyCompany.Api.Merchants.Services.IMerchantFreightService"/>
    <endpoint address="mexMerchantFreightService"
  binding="mexHttpBinding"
  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service name="MyCompany.Services.Merchants.MerchantAuctionService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Proto.Common.EndpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Common" contract="MyCompany.Api.Pricing.Services.IMerchantAuctionService"/>
    <endpoint address="mexMerchantAuctionService"
  binding="mexHttpBinding"
  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I have tried removing the additional mex endpoints but that doesn't make any difference.  Also, I have checked the contracts and they look ok to me.  The IMerchantProductService contract is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.MyCompany.com/services/", Name = "MerchantProductService")]
[ContractClass(typeof(MerchantProductServiceContracts))]
public interface IMerchantProductService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Searchs the merchants product catalog using product name, merchant sku or product global id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchTerm"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    List<MerchantProductQuickSearchItem> QuickSearchMerchantProducts(int merchantId, string searchTerm);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a merchant product based on the Id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ourMerchantProductId">The id of the product to get</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    MerchantProduct GetMerchantProduct(int ourMerchantProductId, int merchantId);

    ///etc.

}
```

and the IMerchantService contract is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.MyCompany.com/services/", Name = "MerchantService")]
[ContractClass(typeof(MerchantServiceContracts))]
public interface IMerchantService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a merchant instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="merchantId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    Merchant GetMerchant(int merchantId);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a merchant's bid settings
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="merchantId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    MerchantBidSettings GetMerchantBidSettings(int merchantId);

    //etc.
}
```

Things I have tried so far:

1. Change everything to basicHttpBinding. Made no difference.
2. Removed the Protobuf behavior configuration.  Made no difference.
3. Remove the individual mex endpoints.  Made no difference
4. Tried different clients (WCFStorm, WCF Test Client) and all report the wrong contract
5. Checked that the individual svc files are implementing the expected contract (they are).

I guess my questions are 1) Is this even possible (i.e. multiple .svc files with IIS hosting) and if so 2) is there something wrong with my config that may be causing my problem.

Comment: I think you need only one <service> node with multiple <endpoint> nodes. You should be able to do this.

Comment: Hi...thanks, but that wouldn't work in my instance as I have multiple services each with their own contract.  The solution was given below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the content of each .svc file. Are you referencing the correct service implementation?
You need web.config + .svc file + c# contract definition + c# service implementation to get it plumbed.

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#"
    Debug="true"
    Service="MyCompany.Services.Merchants.MerchantService" %>
```

Comment: Yes....thanks...that was the solution.  I know I mentioned in my question that I had checked that the svc file implemented the right contract, but I didn't think to check the markup for the svc file.  I originally had one big service which I broke up, and so copied and pasted the svc files, which of course kept the wrong service in the markup.  Thanks!!!

Comment: If you double-click the svc file, it opens the cs file so I had forgotten the markup existed! Wrong namespace in there.